# How to "flatten" a list variable?

Tags: bash

In one of my bash scripts I have this variable, containing a list of directories to be excluded from `tar`, plus their parent directory to be processed:

```
EXLIST="\
 --exclude='/data/sub1/*' \
 --exclude='/data/sub2/*' \
 --exclude='/data/sub3/*' \
 /data \
 "

echo ${EXLIST} | /usr/bin/xargs -0 tar -cf _data.tar
```

However, tar cowardly refuses to create an empty archive because what it really receives after substituting `${EXLIST}` is:

```
echo --exclude='/data/sub1/*' | /usr/bin/xargs -0 tar -cf /home/_data.tar
```

Which tells me that newlines are getting in the way?

I could of course define `EXLIST` as one long line but I prefer not to, as this makes the list less readable.

Is there a way, in **bash**, to "flatten" the lines to a string, so that `tar` can process it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an array in this case, without xargs.

```
EXLIST=("--exclude='/data/sub1/*'" \
        "--exclude='/data/sub2/*'" \
        "--exclude='/data/sub3/*'" \
        "/data")

tar -cf _data.tar "${EXLIST[@]}"
```

Using this method, each element of the array is a separate argument for tar.

Comment: Actually the only difference between my string-based EXLIST and your array-based EXLIST, **when echoed**, is 2 spaces (in mine) vs. 1 (in yours). But...your answer helped me zero in on the problem which was passing `${EXLIST}` as a parameter to another script without the quotations marks. Once I changed `${EXLIST[@]}` to `"${EXLIST[@]}"`, both forms worked very well. So accepting your answer.

Comment: @ateiob I think that you may have a misunderstanding how how quotes and arrays work. What it outputs when echoed is not the same as how it is passed as arguments to command. I recommend the following for reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005

Comment: You're saying exactly what I said in my comment... No misunderstanding. Thanks.